# What's the "right" way to convert data from one type to another?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious as to what the "right" way to convert builtin types is in .NET. Currently i use `Convert.To[type]([variable])` without any null checking or anything. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many types have a TryParse method that you could use. For example:

```
string input = null;
bool result;
Boolean.TryParse(input, out result);
// result ...
```

The above is valid and won't throw an exception when the input to parse is null.

When it comes to converting items to a string, you can almost always rely on calling the ToString() method on the object. However, calling it on a null object will throw an exception.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // valid, returns String.Empty
StringBuilder sb = null;
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // invalid, throws a NullReferenceException
```

One exception is calling ToString() on a nullable type, which would also return String.Empty.

```
int? x = null;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); // no exception thrown
```

Thus, be careful when calling ToString; depending on the object, you may have to check for null explicitly.

Comment: my favorite is when I see code like this:  string test = "123";  txtBox.Text = test.ToString();  lol

Answer (score 3):

See this [link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/266654-casting-vs-using-convert-methods).

> For the most part, casting says "This
>   object of type A is really an object
>   of type B-derived-from-A"
>   Convert.To*() functions say This
>   object isn't a type B, but there
>   exists a way to convert to type B"

Comment: I understand what a conversion *is* but i want to know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Some types such as `int` (`Int32`) have a `TryParse` method. 
If such a method exists, I try to use that. 
Otherwise, I do a null check then pretty much `Convert.To` as you outlined.

Not sure if there is a "right" way, like most tasks it is contextual.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation.  My best advice would be to study up and become familiar, so you can make better choices on your own, but you should probably start by looking into the following

```
System.Int32.TryParse()
```

(there are equivalents for most base types)

> DateTime.ParseExact()